# Rails Installing TypeScript doesn't load any files anymore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, typescript, webpack

I have a problem. In my Rails application I wanted to use TypeScript using webpacker. To install the TypeScript implementation I did the following:
I ran:

```
rails webpacker:install:typescript
```

Then edited the `tsconfig.json` by changing the module setting to `"es6"` and added `"strict": true`

Then I ran: `rails webpacker:compile`. After that I can see in the output that it compiled the following typescript files:

```
Compiling...
Compiled all packs in /app/public/packs
Hash: 0aff66e45830e2859a39
Version: webpack 4.46.0
Time: 1266ms
Built at: 12/07/2022 10:05:05 AM
                                             Asset       Size  Chunks                         Chunk Names
            js/application-ee3dc001e34e3c7c97e6.js   1.02 KiB       0  [emitted] [immutable]  application
         js/application-ee3dc001e34e3c7c97e6.js.br  466 bytes          [emitted]              
         js/application-ee3dc001e34e3c7c97e6.js.gz  537 bytes          [emitted]              
        js/application-ee3dc001e34e3c7c97e6.js.map   5.54 KiB       0  [emitted] [dev]        application
     js/application-ee3dc001e34e3c7c97e6.js.map.br   1.92 KiB          [emitted]              
     js/application-ee3dc001e34e3c7c97e6.js.map.gz    2.2 KiB          [emitted]              
       js/hello_typescript-db05426ac67e3cfab42d.js   1.02 KiB       1  [emitted] [immutable]  hello_typescript
    js/hello_typescript-db05426ac67e3cfab42d.js.br  487 bytes          [emitted]              
    js/hello_typescript-db05426ac67e3cfab42d.js.gz  539 bytes          [emitted]              
   js/hello_typescript-db05426ac67e3cfab42d.js.map   4.91 KiB       1  [emitted] [dev]        hello_typescript
js/hello_typescript-db05426ac67e3cfab42d.js.map.br   1.68 KiB          [emitted]              
js/hello_typescript-db05426ac67e3cfab42d.js.map.gz    1.9 KiB          [emitted]              
                                     manifest.json  738 bytes          [emitted]              
                                  manifest.json.br  172 bytes          [emitted]              
                                  manifest.json.gz  205 bytes          [emitted]              
Entrypoint application = js/application-ee3dc001e34e3c7c97e6.js js/application-ee3dc001e34e3c7c97e6.js.map
Entrypoint hello_typescript = js/hello_typescript-db05426ac67e3cfab42d.js js/hello_typescript-db05426ac67e3cfab42d.js.map
[0] ./app/javascript/packs/application.ts 845 bytes {0} [built]
[1] ./app/javascript/packs/hello_typescript.ts 200 bytes {1} [built]
```

In my application.html.erb I have the following default imports in the head:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload", defer: true %>
```

But this results in an error on the 3th line with:

```
The asset "application.js" is not present in the asset pipeline.
```

I also tried renaming the `app/javascript/packs/application.ts` file to a `.js` file, but that results in the same error. The other thing I tried was adding a `application.js` file to `app/javascript`, to see if the error is caused by the fact that it is now placed in a `packs` foler, but also no luck with that
What am I missing here?